# How can I generate a fully-formatted Excel document as a final output?

Tags: r, excel

I have built a script that extracts data from numerous backend systems and I want the output to be formatted like this:

[image]

Which package is the best and/or easiest to do this with?

I am aware of the `xlsx` package, but am also aware that there are others available so would like to know which is best in terms of ease and/or simplicity to achieve my desired output.

**A little more detail:**

If I run the report across seven days, then the resulting data frame is 168 rows deep (1 row represents 1 hour, 168 hours per week).  I want each date (00:00 - 23:00) to be broken out into day-long blocks, as per the image I have provided.

(Also note that I am in London, England, and as such am currently in timezone UTC+1, which means that right now, the hourly breakdown for each date will range from 01:00 - 00:00 on the next day because our backend systems run on the UTC timezone and that is fine.)

At present, I copy and paste (transpose) the values across manually, but want to be able to fully automate the process so that I can run the script (function), and have the resulting output looking like the image.

This is what the current final output looks like:

[image]

Comment: I often use `xlsx` for this purpose - here is a great post that I followed when making my first excel final output: http://sthda.com/english/wiki/wiki.php?title=r2excel-read-write-and-format-easily-excel-files-using-r-software this one has many great suggestions good examples.

Comment: if you want to know more about transposing data you will need to provide some of your data `dput(df)` so other users can help

Comment: @Mike I don't need help with transposing data; that is easy: `t(df)`. My question relates more generally to structuring the final Excel workbook, of which transposing the data is a small part.

Answer (score 0):

Try the package `openxlsx`. The package offers a lot of custom formatting for .xslx documents and is actively developed / fairly responsive to githhub issues. The vignettes [on the cran website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) are particularly useful.